# red5 v0.9: convert from org.red5.io.utils.ObjectMap to a class

Tags: java, red5

I'm using red5 v0.9 latest svn version.

the function `appConnect(Iconnection conn,Object[] params)`

provides an array of type ObjectMap.

i would like to convert params[0] to the ConnectParams class that i created:

```
public class ConnectParams extends Object {

    public Double toolkitVersion;
    public String gameName;
    public Integer userId;
    public Integer challengeId;

}
```

When i try to convert using the following command:
    ConnectParams param = (ConnectParams)params[0];

i get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.red5.io.utils.ObjectMap cannot be cast to com.xpogames.ConnectParams
```

on the Flash side i have the same definition of that same class and i'm sending it as a parameter.

on the red5 java side, if i print params[0].toString() i do see all the keys and values from the ConnectParams class that i sent, which means that the only thing i'm missing is how to convert this ObjectMap to the appropriate class type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by casting params[0] to a hashmap and passing it to my class's constructor,
in that class i use .get() and .containsKey() in order to populate my class:

```
ConnectParams param = new ConnectParams((HashMap<String,Object>)params[0]);
```